# use auto complete in multiple input fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

Hope all are doing good. well i am running into a issue where i wish to display city names from database in 2 input fields of the same form but everytime i select on both input fields the same value gets selected.

would appreciate if someone could look into my codes and help me out solving this issue.

here is my search.php

```
require_once 'includes/config.php';

  if (isset($_POST['query'])) {
    $inpText = $_POST['query'];
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM pt_cities WHERE cityName LIKE :cityName';
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute(['cityName' => '%'.$inpText.'%']);
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();

    if ($result) {
      foreach ($result as $row) {
        echo '<a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action border-1">'.$row['cityName'].' ('.$row['code'].')</a>';
      }
    } else {
      echo '<p class="list-group-item border-1">No Record</p>';
    }
  }
```

here is my js

```
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
  // Send Search Text to the server
  $(".search").keyup(function () {
    let searchText = $(this).val();
    if (searchText != "") {
      $.ajax({
        url: "search.php",
        method: "post",
        data: {
          query: searchText,
        },
        success: function (response) {
          $(".show-list").html(response);
        },
      });
    } else {
      $(".show-list").html("");
    }
  });
  // Set searched text in input field on click of search button
  $(document).on("click", "a", function () {
    $(".search").val($(this).text());
    $(".show-list").html("");
  });
});
    </script>
```

and my form looks like this

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
                    <label class="form-label-outside">From</label>
                    <div class="form-wrap form-wrap-inline">
                       <input class="form-input search" name="from" type="text" >
                       <div class="list-group show-list">        
                    </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <label class="form-label-outside">To</label>
                    <div class="form-wrap form-wrap-inline">
                      <input class="form-input search"  name="to" type="text" >
                       <div class="list-group show-list">        
                    </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
```

thanks for your help in advance

Answer (score 0):

Welcome! If I understand you correctly, the issue is that your autocomplete result for one input appears in both divs with class `show-list`. The problem is:

```
$(".show-list").html(response)
```

Since `".show-list"` selects both divs with class `"show-list"`, the HTML for both divs is edited, even though you are only focusing on the value of one input. You'll have to differentiate the two `show-list` divs and their respective inputs somehow. Why don't you give each element an ID and make two separate jQuery event listeners?

```
...
<input id="from-input" class="form-input search" name="from" type="text">
<div id="from-show-list" class="list-group show-list"></div>
...
<input id="to-input" class="form-input search"  name="to" type="text">
<div id="to-show-list" class="list-group show-list"></div>
```

```
$("#from-input").keyup(function () {
    let searchText = $(this).val();
    if (searchText != "") {
      $.ajax({
        url: "search.php",
        method: "post",
        data: {
          query: searchText,
        },
        success: function (response) {
          $("#from-show-list").html(response);
        },
      });
    } else {
      $("#from-show-list").html("");
    }
  });
```

```
$("#to-input").keyup(function () {
    let searchText = $(this).val();
    if (searchText != "") {
      $.ajax({
        url: "search.php",
        method: "post",
        data: {
          query: searchText,
        },
        success: function (response) {
          $("#to-show-list").html(response);
        },
      });
    } else {
      $("#to-show-list").html("");
    }
  });
```

Comment: Thanks mate but now the results are not getting clicked

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by the results aren't getting clicked? As in these two functions don't work, or the generated results in the `show-list` divs aren't working now?

Comment: the results are getting fetched but when i click upon it nothing is getting entered inside the input box

Comment: Did clicking on the results work as expected before these changes? If not, there may be issues with these `a` elements being dynamically generated after the event listener is declared.